# How to echo values from two indexed arrays in an alternating fashion?

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, echo, alternating

I have this code:

```
<?php 
$arrayName2 = array('123', '567');
$arrayName3 = array('abc', 'def');
$arrayName[] = $arrayName2;
$arrayName[] = $arrayName3;
foreach ($arrayName as $key) {
    foreach($key as $innerKey) {
        echo $innerKey;
    }
}
?>
```

And it brings: `123567abcdef`. How can I get `123abc567def`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using `array_map()` and `implode()`:

```
$arrayName2 = array('123', '567');
$arrayName3 = array('abc', 'def');

$result=implode(array_map(function($v1,$v2){return $v1.$v2;},$arrayName2,$arrayName3));
echo $result;
// output: 123abc567def
```

---

Or if you are simply echoing and don't need a variable, this will be more efficient than Adhan's solution because it doesn't have to modify the input data:

```
array_map(function($v1,$v2){echo $v1,$v2;},$arrayName2,$arrayName3);
// output: 123abc567def
```

---

And finally, this is a more efficient foreach version because `array_combine()` is unnecessary:

```
foreach($arrayName2 as $k=>$a){
    echo $a,$arrayName3[$k];
}
// output: 123abc567def
```

Comment: This one is even better! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
$arrayName2 = array('123', '567');
$arrayName3 = array('abc', 'def');
$arrayName = array_combine($arrayName2,$arrayName3);
foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.$value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < yourendvariable; $i = i + 2) {
    echo "arrayname[i] arrayname2[i + 1]";
}
```